# how to build an associative array like this

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var dictionary = {
    "cats": [1,2,3,4,5], 
    "dogs": [6,7,8,9,10]
};
```

how to build an array like the above javascript?

have worked out but not working.

```
var abc={};

abc[key_name]=[];
abc[key_name].push(key_value);

had an another array 

for(i in array_1)
{
  key_name=array_1.key;
  key_value=array_1.value;
  abc[key_name]=[];
  abc[key_name].push(key_value);
}
```

Comment: `key_name` isn't defined! The error console would tell you that.

Comment: Please define "_not working_". Also show the real code you have, you might have obfuscated the "not working" part in the current snippet.

Comment: had an another array 

for(i in array_1)
{
key_name=array_1.key;
key_value=array_1.value;
abc[key_name]=[];
abc[key_name].push(key_value);
}

Comment: You've a `for..in` loop, where the looping variable `i` holds the name of the current key on every round of the iteration. Use that instead of self-made variables which both store `undefined`. Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) is always useful.

Comment: here problem is not getting the values or not sort of i need to build an array as "var dictionary"

Comment: No? What you expect the value of `array_1.key` to be? There's no such a property in your object, and it is not mysteriously added into it in the `for..in` loop.

Comment: Did you want to merge it or what? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]. Your broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation that also includes sample input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this in the following way 
if you have an array of the following format [{"key" : key, "value" : value}, ...]

```
var abc={};

for(let element of array_1)
{
    key_name=element.key;
    key_value=element.value;
    if(abc[key_name] === undefined)
        abc[key_name]=[];
    abc[key_name].push(key_value);
}
```